# Sorting datetime by looping through multiple dataframes using globals() as a variable reference

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, datetime, global

I have 20 dataframes of the following format but with 140000 or so lines. The data format is '%Y/%m/%d' or YYYY/MM/DD

```
In [1]:  data1 = pd.DataFrame({'Day': ['2020-04-07','2020-04-07', '2020-04-07','2020-08-11','2020-08-11','2020-08-11','2020-06-14','2020-06-14','2020-06-14'],
                           'Time': ['23:41:18', '23:42:56', '23:44:34','10:23:10','15:24:46','10:24:13','23:41:18','23:42:56','23:44:34'],
                           'V': [1044.865, 1044.889, 1044.914,320.014,320.033,320.018,1044.865,1044.889,1044.914]})
        
        data2 = pd.DataFrame({'Day': ['2020-04-07','2020-04-07', '2020-04-07','2020-08-11','2020-08-11','2020-08-11','2020-06-14','2020-06-14','2020-06-14'],
                           'Time': ['23:41:18', '23:42:56', '23:44:34','10:23:10','15:24:46','10:24:13','23:41:18','23:42:56','23:44:34'],
                           'V': [1044.865, 1044.887, 1044.914,320.014,320.033,320.018,1044.865,1044.889,1044.914]})
        
        data3 = pd.DataFrame({'Day': ['2020-04-07','2020-04-07', '2020-04-07','2020-08-11','2020-08-11','2020-08-11','2020-06-14','2020-06-14','2020-06-14'],
                           'Time': ['23:41:18', '23:42:56', '23:44:34','10:23:10','15:24:46','10:24:13','23:41:18','23:42:56','23:44:34'],
                           'V': [1044.865, 1044.888, 1044.914,320.014,320.033,320.018,1044.865,1044.889,1044.914]})

    In [2]:data2.head(15)
    Out[2]: 
          Day         Time        V
    0  2020-04-07   23:41:18   1044.865
    1  2020-04-07   23:42:56   1044.887 
    2  2020-04-07   23:44:34   1044.914
    3  2020-08-11   10:23:10   320.014
    4  2020-08-11   15:24:46   320.033
    5  2020-08-11   10:24:13   320.018
    6  2020-06-14   23:41:18   1044.865
    7  2020-06-14   23:42:56   1044.889
    8  2020-06-14   23:44:34   1044.914
```

And and I'm using the following loop to try and sort the dataframes by the dates in the column 'Day' and then by the 'Time' column. In my actual dataframe I can have around 3 measures for each minute.

My purpose is to not have to type the dataframe names 20 times, and this is the solution I found that works quite well with .index  .drop()  .reset_index() attributes.
But not with the .sort_values() as seen in this loop for some reason:

```
 In [3]:for n in range(1,4,1):
            globals()["data" + str(n)]['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(globals()["data" + str(n)]['Day'], 
            format = '%Y/%m/%d')
            globals()["data" + str(n)].sort_values(by=['Day','Time'])
            globals()["data" + str(n)]['Day'] = globals()["data" + str(n)]['Day'].astype(str)
 Out[3]: 
          Day         Time        V
    0  2020-04-07   23:41:18   1044.865
    1  2020-04-07   23:42:56   1044.887 
    2  2020-04-07   23:44:34   1044.914
    3  2020-08-11   10:23:10   320.014
    4  2020-08-11   15:24:46   320.033
    5  2020-08-11   10:24:13   320.018
    6  2020-06-14   23:41:18   1044.865
    7  2020-06-14   23:42:56   1044.889
    8  2020-06-14   23:44:34   1044.914
```

But if i just use the loop to make the 'Date' column a 'datetime' and then use the .sort_values() by manually typing the dataframe name it works.

```
 In [4]:for n in range(1,4,1):
            globals()["data" + str(n)]['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(globals()["data" + str(n)]['Day'], 
            format = '%Y/%m/%d')
        data2.sort_values(by=['Day','Time'])

 Out[3]: 
          Day         Time        V
    0  2020-04-07   23:41:18   1044.865
    1  2020-04-07   23:42:56   1044.887 
    2  2020-04-07   23:44:34   1044.914
    6  2020-06-14   23:41:18   1044.865
    7  2020-06-14   23:42:56   1044.889
    8  2020-06-14   23:44:34   1044.914
    3  2020-08-11   10:23:10   320.014
    4  2020-08-11   10:24:13   320.018
    5  2020-08-11   15:24:46   320.033
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work in a more dynamic way?

Comment: First thing first: **stop using `globals()`!** It’s almost *never* appropriate. For your use-case a dictionary or a regular list might be appropriate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil

Comment: I will look into that, thanks for the link!

Comment: You have to use temp variable or inplace argument inside sort_values.